# All Equation tools editor required

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, mathjax

I'm looking for a free editor that have all equation tools. I have searched a lot but have not found. I want this editor for php.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a serverside calculator? Try this one: [http://w2scripts.com/calculators/1710/php-calc](http://w2scripts.com/calculators/1710/php-calc)

Comment: Since you tagged this question under `ckeditor`, perhaps the [mathjax plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah i know that but they have a lot of thing missing.suppose. matrix,tendis to limt here@Atzmon

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no universal WYSIWYG editor that works with MathJax (I would know otherwise :).

Mainly because MathJax is not designed for WYSIWYG. [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/) is, in some way, but it supports a subset of LaTeX and will hardly fit your needs if you want something universal.

What is likely to be found is a LaTeX editor with live preview. [CodeCogs](http://www.codecogs.com/eqneditor) is a good candidate, although there can be some others which I haven't heard of. Once LaTeX is written, you can render it with MathJax, or just keep the CodeCogs image (it's better to save, they have some limitations on the number of usages per day if you use their service for free).

Comment: CodeCogs how i will use that in my site. i want editor they just provide image me